# What is the chance of iron spawning at a particular level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I keep on running out of iron, and it's getting tiresome spending time searching a certain level that doesn't even have iron.

So how much Iron can spawn at once and at which y level?

Comment: "How much Iron can spawn *at once*" - this is irrelevant. Ores spawn in chunks and chunks are created almost indefinitely, so there is almost limitless amounts of the stuff.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Minecraft Wiki article on iron ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore):

> Iron occurs only around from bedrock to slightly above sea level (layers 1-63). However, almost all of the iron ore will be at the lower levels. On average, there are about 77 iron ores per chunk.

So, you will find the most iron ore if you look pretty close to bedrock. You can see what level you're on by pressing F3 and looking at the 'Y' coordinate.

Comment: +1 but for me, iron is very common near surface and mid-level caves. I'm surprised the OP can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

The game will attempt to generate 20 times per chunk in veins of size 1-14, from y-levels 0-63. If you find a cave, chances of finding iron and other ores such as diamond are higher. Iron is found in any **Overworld** biome, even the oceans. Iron can also be found in shipwrecks, spawner chests, village chests, mineshaft minecart chests, etc...

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore

Comment: Can you add some evidence to support your answer? Like a link or screenshot of where you got the info from.